# Highlighting start and end tags?

Tags: html, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, ide

I'm currently evaluating Sublime Text Editor (build 3126). One of the features I would like in an editor is to clearly highlight the start and end tags in source code.

At present, in Sublime, I see it as a very subtle highlight (small dotted underline) as shown in the image

[image: Sublime]

Is there a way I can make it more pronounced? Something like giving it a background color to the entire `div` word? Is that configurable?

Answer (score 1):

The **[BracketHighlighter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BracketHighlighter)** package, despite its name, supports HTML/XML tags (among other enclosings). It supports [customization](https://facelessuser.github.io/BracketHighlighter/customize/), even for new languages.

It may overlap with the dotted underline of Sublime, but it's better than not noticing at first glance.

Comment: does anyone know:  how to change "default" html tag highlighting "length" in sublime text 3?  (it seems to work only when there aren't many lines between the opening and closing tags, but if there are, say, 60 lines, it doesn't work ) i can see the setting `"auto_match_enabled": true` and `"match_brackets": true` in sublime text settings, but they don't define length